# How do i create a webhook to handoff live agent from dialogflow cx to ccai platform?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I've been able to connect my agent on dialogflow cx to ccai platoform using service accounts, how do i configure the live agent handoff part in my agent to connect to ccai platform when that intent is detected?

Nothing yet, because i'm confused